# Update entire object in c# .net EF with HttpPut without having to specify all variables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a API and I want to update an object. It's working fine right now, but I haven't included all data yet. The list of `foundPerson.somevalue = person.somevalue` will be very long with all this data. Is there a shorter way of updating the object? It would be nice if I could just update the entire object instead of having to specify all values. I tried `foundpersond = person` but that does not work.

My code:

```
public Person UpdatePerson(Person person)
        {
            var foundPerson = _appDbContext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(result => result.name == person.name);
            if(foundPerson != null)
            {
                foundPerson.value1.anothervalue1 = person.value1.anothervalue1;
                foundPerson.value1.anothervalue2 = person.value1.anothervalue2;
                foundPerson.value2.anothervalue1 = person.value2.anothervalue1;
                foundPerson.value2.anothervalue2 = person.value2.anothervalue2;
                foundPerson.value2.anothervalue3 = person.value2.anothervalue3;

                _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
                return foundPerson;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Edit: This is how my Person class and the value classes look like.

```
public class Person
    {
        public Value1 Value1 { get; set; }
        public Value2 Value2 { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Value1
    {
        public string Anothervalue1 { get; set; }
        public string Anothervalue2 { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Value2
    {
        public string Anothervalue1 { get; set; }
        public string Anothervalue2 { get; set; }
        public string Anothervalue3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are `value1` and `value2` value objects? I assume so, just making sure.

Comment: you can just "bind" your object to your context rather than bringing it from the database

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/explicit-tracking#updating-existing-entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_appDbContext.Entry(foundPerson).CurrentValues.SetValues(person);
```

I think it won't work well on Value1 and Value 2 so you might need to use the same approach on them

Comment: This worked for me:
`_appDbContext.Entry(foundPerson.Value1).CurrentValues.SetValues(person.Value1);`
Same thing for Value2. Thanks for the answer!